# Creating a new site collection from an exisiting site collection with (without creating a template)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-online

We have got a Group SharePoint 2013 site, which has got a lot of contents (documents) in it. We have tried to create a template of this site so that we can create a new site from this template but we are getting long file name error messages.

I am wondering if there is any other way of creating a new site collection from an existing site with contents?

We are using cloud based version of SharePoint 2013.

Comment: I think there is no other way of creating new site collection from an existing site without using template.

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Online version you don't have options to export the entire site (maybe with Sharegate, Avepoint solutions do). But one question, do you have SharePoint Online or SharePoint 2013 on Premise in dedicated cloud server?

If you have SharePoint online you could access the site via web services or PowerShell with only a few commands available and maybe retrieving groups and content via web services could work.

By the other hand if you are using SharePoint 2013 in an Azure Machine for example you could export the Site via PowerShell with the `Export-SPWeb` command.

http://passionatetechie.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/export-import-sharepoint-site-using-web.html this site also could fit for your needs but never Out Od The Box